# Why is my each loop printing in reverse order

Tags: jquery

The content inside my body tag looks like the following:

```
<div class="list_container">
  <ul class="list_content">
      <li style="display: none;" class="first"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="box_wrapper">

<section id="about" class="scroller">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus dignissimos voluptas quisquam, quaerat, illum animi fuga nihil nesciunt assumenda cupiditate consectetur ipsam officia magni reiciendis nisi dolor natus autem consequatur.</section>
<section id="product" class="scroller">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate repellendus inventore molestias tempore distinctio natus cumque voluptatibus ullam blanditiis dicta, a, porro eum, modi nobis aliquam voluptatum voluptates repudiandae sunt?</section>
<section id="services" class="scroller">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facilis totam id consectetur mollitia inventore distinctio corporis eius impedit commodi. Voluptas, dicta non. Reprehenderit aperiam perferendis labore beatae veritatis tenetur harum.</section>
</div>
```

I want to loop through all the sections that use the class scroller, and then print list items with a tags. Each a tag will use the id of its respective section as href.

I am managing to print the list items, but for some reason, it's printing in reverse order.

Eg:

section has id o about

section has id of services

The lists should be in the same order:

```
<li><a class='bullet' href="#about">Test</a></li>
<li><a class='bullet' href="services">Test</a></li>
```

However, on my side it prints in reverse when I inspect the page:

```
<li><a class='bullet' href="services">Test</a></li>
<li><a class='bullet' href="#about">Test</a></li>
```

My js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var numItems = $('.scroller').length;

    $('.scroller').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        var getId = $(this).attr('id');
        $( "<li><a class='bullet' href='#" + getId +"'>Test</a></li>" ).insertAfter( "li.first" );
    });
    console.log(numItems);    
});
```

updated:

To highlight each bullet on click, I did the following:

```
$("li a.bullet").on('click', function(){
    $('li a.bullet').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

How can I also highlight the bullets on mouse scroll and/or using the vertical scrollbar?
So, if I am under About section, the first bullet should be highlighted and so on.

My updated pen can be found [here with the full code](https://codepen.io/melodiacapoeira/pen/GLQWBo?editors=1111)

Comment: Given they are in the order "about", "product", "services" in the HTML and the codepen console outputs them as "about", "product", "services", it's not clear what the problem actually is

Comment: because you are always inserting after the first LI which is hidden but still there.

Comment: The pen doesn't include any `.insertAfter` - can you decide if you want us to look at the pen or the code here? If the pen, include all the code in the pen.

Comment: `.insertAfter( "li.first" )` will put them in reverse order - cange to `.insertAfter( "li.last" )`

Comment: @freedomn-m I just updated my pen

Comment: Still not seeing a problem - can see the 3 dots on the right, but they appear to be in the correct order (despite the insert-after-first)

Comment: @Jamiec looked legit to me - would likely create the same answer if I could see it not-working first

Comment: @freedomn-m at some point I got confused but used the appendTo instead and removed the list tag from the HTML and it is working.
I know is probably out of topic, but would there be a way can highlight each bullet as scroll to its respective section?

Comment: In the click: `$(this).closest("li").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active")` and add css for `li.active`

Comment: You might be able to undelete @Jamiec's answer and upvote/accept it

Comment: @freedomn-m I assume he deleted his own answer because only the owner of the post can delete his own post. And I had noticed that for some reason, someone downvoted his answer as well as my question.
I will update my question if you don't mind supporting on that.

Comment: TBH - edit should really be a new question, but I guess there's no undeleted answers so probably ok

Comment: For the edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27081526/2181514

Comment: @freedomn-m the answer works like a charm and I upvoted .)